# Jquery Event Bubbling CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a form with checkboxes and then text to the right of the checkbox.  There are jquery events attached to the click events of the the checkbox.  What I want is to allow the user to click on the label or the checkbox and have the checkbox check/uncheck and the event to fire.  Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do (**DON'T** run the code as below as it creates an endless loop).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form p").click(function() {
    $(this).find("input").click();
  });

  $("form input").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });  
});
</script>


<form>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="checker" value="1" /> Click anywhere</p>
<p> <input type="checkbox" name="checker2" value="2" /> Click anywhere</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the LABEL tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 2):

clicking on any `<input>` tag triggers the click event of `<p>` tag (because `<input>` tag is inside the `<p>` tag) which then triggers the click event of `<input>` tag leading to an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the 'endless loop' using [jQuery's event.stopPropagation method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).